# In Eclipse, Eclemma coverage view not being shown

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just installed Eclemma in my eclipse and created a JUnit test to be covered.
I runned the test and it succeeded, green and red banners shown in my program, but I can't see any "coverage" view like the instruction shown ( nor in Window-Show View).

How can I resolve this problem? Do I have to re-write my JUnit test or re-install EclEmma?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Window -> Show View -> Other -> select coverage / type coverage.

You will see the java code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the first time, you need to install eclemma from marketplace, after installation it will restart.

Below is the path to find the coverage.

Window >> Show view >> Other >> Type coverage, click on the coverage.

When you do coverage as junit , you can able to see the code coverage.