# How to stop Eclipse coverage every time I run the program

Tags: java, eclipse

Every-time I run my program Eclipse also runs `coverage` how can I turn this off please.

I followed this answer but it only clears the coverage highlights and next time it runs coverage again.

[Clearing coverage highlighting in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112561/clearing-coverage-highlighting-in-eclipse)

[image]

Comment: How are you running your programs? Usually in the eclipse menu under "Run" you can select whether you just want to "Run" or actually have "Coverage" checked as well.

Comment: I just run them in Eclipse `ctrl + shift + F11`, I can find any check box in the Run menu

Comment: @Dave `CTRL + SHIFT + F11` will run coverage. `CTRL + F11` is a normal run without code coverage. But you can also run your program by clicking the corresponding button in the tool bar. There is a button for debugging, next to it the default run (without coverage) and next to it, the coverage run.

Comment: Thanks, silly mistake

Comment: Just right-clicking on the java file (in eclipse) you want to run should also bring up a context menu where you can choose to "Run as", "Debug as" or get "Coverage as".

Comment: Check this solution... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038602/in-eclipse-eclemma-coverage-view-not-being-shown